# Photorealistic Rendering: How To?

Tags: vasp, ab-initio-calculations, crystallography, dielectric-constants

i have started computationally modelling materials from first principles recently, my code of choice being VASP [6.1.0].
Recently i have come across this paper in Nature: **DOI:10.1038/s41567-023-01960-5** and became interested in the images rendered. I wish to adapt it to use with a simple crystal structure I used to practice working with VASP.

I have calculated various properties of my crystal like: relaxed structure, band structure, DoS, absorption and reflectivity data. I attach the reflectivity plot of my structure below:

[image]

**My question is:** given this reflectivity data how do i find the appearance my crystal structure will have if/when synthesized in the lab? Can someone detail the exact steps i need to take to do so?

Comment: +1 You can check in the same paper you have mentioned in your question, take a look at the caption of Figure 4, the authors said: 'The photorealistic render of the high-pressure hydrogen in vacuum is made by feeding the Mitsuba2 software https://github.com/mitsuba-renderer/mitsuba2 with the complex refractive index of hydrogen and introducing a texture to simulate both rough and smooth appearance, following the methodology discussed in this paper https://www.nature.com/articles/s41524-019-0266-0

Comment: @JaafarMehrez i was having a hard time figuring out the working process for this. I am a novice when it comes to ab-initio computations, right now. Thats why i was looking for a proper working methodology in this regard